# Communicate context in Darwin notifications

Tags: macos, core-foundation

I have a macOS application which can theoretically run multiple instances. I want to be able to communicate events to the other running instances using the Darwin notification center (via `CFNotificationCenter`).

I need to not only have a notification name but ideally pass some `userInfo` at the same time. Unfortunately, as the documentation states:

```
// - CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(): the 'object', 'userInfo', and 'deliverImmediately' arguments are ignored.
```

Is there any way, or alternative solution which will let me message other running applications and provide a parameter value along with the name of the notification?

Comment: Do you need the macOS sandbox? The rules are different for Sandboxed vs Non Sandboxed apps.

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess Good point. I don’t need to follow sandboxing requirements, although I’m interested in both.

Comment: If you don't need the sandbox, you can use NSDistributedNotificationCenter which accepts userInfo (when not sandboxed). CFDarwinNotificationCenter can't transport any payload.

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess Perfect! And in Objective-C, not C! Can't believe I missed this...